# What can be the proper meaning of the ‘over’?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> A breeze ruffled the neat hedges of Privet Drive, which lay silent and
>   tidy under the inky sky, the very last place you would expect
>   astonishing things to happen. Harry Potter [a baby] **rolled over**
>   inside his blankets without waking up. One small hand closed on the
>   letter beside him and he slept on, not knowing he was special, not
>   knowing he was famous, not knowing he would be woken in a few hours'
>   time by Mrs. Dursley's scream as she opened the front door to put out
>   the milk bottles, nor that he would spend the next few weeks being
>   prodded and pinched by his cousin Dudley... 
> (Harry Potter and the
>   Sorcerer's Stone)

What’s the meaning of ‘over’ in the example?
(1) If we adopt the meaning of ‘roll’ as "to move or rock from side to side,” I think ‘over’ could mean ‘[repeatedly: adv 11](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/over).’ So the baby might have been swaying in the blanket repeatedly.
(2) If we adopt the ‘rolled’ as a participle, the sentence can be a noun phrase that has a participle in it; ‘rolled over’ could mean ‘[wrapped: v.tr.12a](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/roll) [completely: adv 4](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/over).’ - Next sentence also has participle in its noun phrase (absolute phrase).; for the letter was closed on by an adult.
(3) I think one of the two above would be proper, but ‘roll over completely, 360 degrees’ wouldn’t.
What can be the proper meaning of the ‘over’?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means baby Harry had been sleeping on his back and then he rolled *over* so he was sleeping on his stomach-  or vice versa.

*Over* in this case is the same as in *to turn over* which means to put what was on the bottom, on the top;  *When the steak is browned on one side, turn it **over** in the pan and brown the other side*

Comment: But how could a baby, in the blanket wrapped up – it’s the season of Bonfire Night, November in Britain - and put at the front door, have rolled over as you said: the adult must have tightly wrapped him up that the baby couldn’t rolled over inside?

Comment: What you say may or may not be true for some set of babies in blankets. But in this author's story the baby managed to do it as she has written.

Comment: @Listenever: You're interpreting it too literally. Baby Harry might have been lying on his side, and wriggled/rolled *less than 90°* to be on his back. Besides, he being a ***special*** baby, he might have had extra special super-strength, like Superman.